# AFHTTPSessionManager Subclass Singleton with Configuration in Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2

I am trying to make a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` using Swift. According to the documentation, making a singleton instance of your subclass is recommended. I understand how to make a singleton in Swift, but I need to be able to initialize my singleton with a base URL.

```
class ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager: AFHTTPSessionManager {
  class var sharedManager: ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager {

    struct StaticManager {
      static var instance: ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager? = nil
      static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    if (StaticManager.instance == nil) {
      dispatch_once(&StaticManager.onceToken) {
        StaticManager.instance = ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: myURL)
      }
    }

    return StaticManager.instance!
  }
}
```

How do I allow my singleton instance to be initialized with a configureable parameter?

Thanks

Comment: You can set (and reset) the baseURL after initialization.

Comment: I'm unable to set the `baseURL` after initialize. In the swift header for `AFHTTPSessionManager`: `var baseURL: NSURL! { get }`

Because it's a readonly variable here, I need to initialize my singleton with the baseURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this.

```
public class func createSharedManager(baseURL: NSURL!) -> ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager {
  StaticManager.instance = ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: baseURL)

  return StaticManager.instance!
}

public class var sharedManager: ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager? {
  return StaticManager.instance
}

private struct StaticManager {
 static var instance: ZRUserAuthenticationHTTPSessionManager? = nil
}
```